# flipkart automation script with python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, visual-studio-code

Can some help me with this:
script for https://www.flipkart.com/ where I do following things:
Enter URL in browser
Navigate to mobile section
Display all the mobiles which has RAM >= 6gb and are available in white color (Sort the results in descending order)

I tried but didn't work as required
Please help with full code in python selenium

`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import keyboard
from keyboard import press
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
s=Service("C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")   #excutable service patch
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")
#driver.find_element("xpath", "//button[@class='_2KpZ6l _2doB4z']").click()
keyboard.press_and_release('esc')
driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[contains(text(),'Mobiles')]").click()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element("xpath", "//input[@placeholder='Search for products, brands and more']").send_keys("Mobile with 6GB RAM in white color")
press('enter')
#driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='_4921Z t0pPfW' and @title='8 GB and Above']").click()
#driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='_3FPh42']//div[@class='_2d0we9']//div[@class='_4921Z t0pPfW' and @title='6 GB']").click()
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]').click()
# driver.close()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Add some wait time after pressing Enter:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")
#driver.find_element("xpath", "//button[@class='_2KpZ6l _2doB4z']").click()

keyboard.press_and_release('esc')

driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[contains(text(),'Mobiles')]").click()
driver.find_element("xpath", "//input[@placeholder='Search for products, brands and more']").send_keys("Mobile with 6GB RAM in white color")
time.sleep(1)
press('enter')
time.sleep(2)
#driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='_4921Z t0pPfW' and @title='8 GB and Above']").click()
#driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='_3FPh42']//div[@class='_2d0we9']//div[@class='_4921Z t0pPfW' and @title='6 GB']").click()
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]').click()
```